# I want to share my data to social sites available in my android device. How can I write android code for that in my app?

Tags: android

```
SocAdapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

// Add providers
SocAdapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);
SocAdapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER, R.drawable.twitter);
SocAdapter.addProvider(Provider.LINKEDIN, R.drawable.linkedin);
SocAdapter.addProvider(Provider.MYSPACE, R.drawable.myspace);
SocAdapter.enable(share);
```

I need total social sites in my device . How can I get them dynamically without writing like this.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

These developer links should help you:

This is how i share text based stuff:

```
String text = "this is some text i want to share";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Title"));
```

Comment: it's working but it showing the sending text message.

Comment: will you provide me the andmade share code..........